# How to determine whether my Springboot war file includes an embedded http server or not?

Tags: java, spring

I have an WAR file, which is a Springboot application package. I can unpack it. How do I figure out whether this guy was shipped with an embedded http server included or not? If it does include an embedded http server, I assume I would find its executable under a sub-directory, right?

Comment: Try running it. No need to make it so complicated.

Comment: I got an exception. From the error message I can not tell. The message says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.fineract.ServerWithMariaDB4jApplication

Comment: In that case [it doesn't look like it](https://github.com/reehanlalkhan/imifosx-server/blob/master/fineract-provider/src/main/java/org/apache/fineract/ServerWithMariaDB4jApplication.java).